# Images from network drive wont show when python script converted to exe

Tags: python, path, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I wrote small program to display images from network drive. It works perfectly when is launched as .py,
but when converted to .exe file (using auto-py-to-exe as one directory) program starts but not displays images and returns error "QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap".

I have already tried:

```
path = "\\\\ow-sql\\Users\\file scanner\\Documents\\job_scans_copy\\20206\\012252988_30-06-2020- 
    151531.jpg"
```

```
path = r"\\" + os.path.join("ow-sql", "Users", "file scanner", "Documents", "job_scans_copy","20206","012252988_30-06-2020-151531.jpg")
```

I also tried both \ and /.
I can't simply include file into the build as the files will change and new files will be added.
There is no problem with images from img. folder.
for example:

```
img = QPixmap("img\\image.jpg")
```

works perfect as an exe.

Would you advise me how to fix this problem?

Please find simplified code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QScrollArea
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class ApplicationWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        main_widget = QWidget(self)

        btn = QPushButton("Close", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        img = QPixmap("\\\\ow-sql\\Users\\file scanner\\Documents\\job_scans_copy\\20206\\012252988_30-06-2020-151531.jpg")
        label = QLabel(main_widget)
        pixmap_resized = img.scaled(200, 200)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap_resized)

        scrollArea = QScrollArea(main_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True) 
        scrollArea.setWidget(label)

        l = QVBoxLayout(main_widget)
        l.addWidget(scrollArea)
        l.addWidget(btn)

        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)


    def closeEvent(self, ce):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = ApplicationWindow()
    aw.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem simply by using cx_Freeze to create an executable and everything works perfect.

For some reason pyInstaller does not want to load the image into QLabel if it's not included in build. It doesn't matter if it's a path to the file or the file is loaded as a BLOB from the database. None of them works.

cx_Freeze solved the problem without any additional code changes.